# Manage long running operation with Microsoft Bot framework Composer

Tags: botframework, bots

my bot is developed using Microsoft bot framework composer which is a visual designer.
In my bot, a particular HTTPAction is taking more than 15 seconds. During that 15 seconds, I would like to keep on simulating waiting message for the user. It's a long-running operation. Also, if the user types in something during the waiting period then my bot is expected to say something like "your request is still in progress".

I checked on the internet regarding this but I found solutions only around Bot framework SDK and not for Composer.

Please help me with this as I am stuck for since long.

Comment: Did you tried pro active message

Comment: @VinothRajendran, Is implementing pro active message possible in Microsoft Bot Composer? If yes, can you please help me with the documentation?

Comment: you should write custom action

Comment: Have you looked into something like a typing middleware, so it shows the "..." on the screen, and the user doesn't have the urge to keep typing?

Comment: @JJ..yes..but typing middleware vanishes after 5 secs.My call is taking 15 secs to run.